# Frequency Generation

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I am writing a MATLAB program for finding all possible values of frequencies f_i's which satisfies the following constraints:

```
f1+f2+f3+f4+f5+f6=100 
f2+2*f3+3*f4+4*f5+5*f6=95
```

The program is taking a huge amount of time because of the enormous nested for loops and yet I couldn't get an answer to it, so what would be the possible solution to this problem?

Also my real problem is much more bigger, I need to have all possible frequencies for like 150 f_i's with similar constraints as

```
f1+f2+...+f150=10,000,000
f2+3*f3+...+17*f150=9,500,000
```

So, is there any way or technique to tackle such problems, if yes then how?

Comment: If you don't have more than two constraints, there is an infinite number of solutions

Comment: Also, this should probably be moved to the Math or Physics SE sites.

Comment: It seems that the question is on enumerating all the solutions given that f_1 .. f_n are integers with likely additional constraints (given that they are frequencies).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loops, you need linear algebra.  You have 2 linear equations and 6 variables. This leaves you 4 degrees of freedom.

I am assuming that your variables are integers constrained to some range, otherwise there is an infinite amount of solutions.

Assign integer values into `f1`,`f2`,`f3`,`f4` and solve the remaining equations. One way to do it is to generate a 4D grid of all integers in some range, and solve the linear systems.

```
[f1,f2,f3,f4] = ndgrid(1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10);
res = [1 1; 4 5] \ ([100-f1(:)-f2(:)-f3(:)-f4(:)  95-f2(:)-2*f3(:)-3*f4(:)]');
f5 = res(1,:);
f6 = res(2,:);

solutions = [f1(:) f2(:) f3(:) f4(:) f5(:) f6(:)]
```

Comment: I can see it works but I need the frequencies to be non-zero positive integers. Now can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The example problem you give has 6 unknowns, and only 2 equations. In your real problem, you say you can have 150 variables, but still only have 2 equations.

These problems are grossly under-determined, and there is an infinite amount of different values you could assign to `f1--f150` that will satisfy both constraints. Enumerating all the possible solutions is pointless -- you're better off generating an array for each frequency, and upon using a specific combination, check the constraints. This is far more efficient, since there are so little constraints to begin with.

Now, you say all the `f_i` are non-zero positive integers. That still doesn't help, since `1/0` is also an integer. I assume there is one additional constraint, and that is that all frequencies may not be larger than some predefined maximum value.

I'll give you an illustration of my concern. Suppose that maximum value is 100. Then how many different combinations are there? For 6 different frequencies (as in the example),

```
num_fi = 100*100*100*100*100*100 = 100^6 = 10^12 = 1 trillion
```

combinations. For `f_i` with `i = 150`,

```
num_fi = 100*100*...150 times...*100 = 100^150 = 10 ^ 300
```

(that's ten-to-the-power-300!) different combinations.

Suppose you want to store them. Since integers between 1 and 100 consume only 1 byte, you'll have to store

```
[number of combinations] * [number of f_i in the set] * [number of bytes]  
    = [num_fi] * i * 1byte 
    = (10^300 * 150) bytes
    = 1.5 * 10^290 TERABYTES.
```

Supposing you use 4TB harddrives, and each harddrive is 1cm high, you'll need

```
3.75 * 10^289
```

4TB harddrives. These harddrives, when stacked on top of each other, will create a tower that will reach

```
(3.75*0.01*10^289)/384400000/2 = 4.87 * 10^278
```

times [to the moon](https://www.google.nl/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=distance+to+the+moon&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=3lqBUIqBGtLM0AXJlYG4Cw) and back, or

```
(3.75*0.01*10^289)/2.54e6/9.4605284e15/2 = 7.80 * 10^264
```

times to the [Andromeda galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy) and back, or

```
(3.75*0.01*10^289)/13.2e9/9.4605284e15/2    
= 1.50 * 10^261
```

times to [UDFj-39546284](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDFj-39546284) *and back*.

Since it's Friday, I'll throw in a few bonuses:

The harddrives would fill up:

- 1.59e+247 times the sphere, centred at the Sun and with radius 39AU (to Pluto)
- 3.75e+222 times the sphere, centred at the SMB at the galaxy's centre and radius 100,000 lightyears (the entire galaxy)
- 1.39e+207 times the sphere, centred at the Earth and radius 13.9 billion light years (the observable universe)

And that's just for a maximum value of 100.

So there's really not much we can do here, unless **you give us more context on what you're trying to accomplish with the `f_i`'s**.

Comment: Yes, MATLAB will assign a lot of zeros to most of the frequencies, but I don't need such solutions. The frequencies has to be non-zero positive integers satisfying those conditions. Can we without running a program for it enumerate the all possible combinations satisfying those 2 conditions

Comment: lol wait now i'm doubting myself. 100^6 *isn't* 10 million right??

Comment: @AK4749: Oh haha, time to go home obviously. You're right -- 100^6 = (10^2)^6 = 10^12 = 1 trillion. I'll edit.

Comment: OMG!! let me draft my problem more clearly and get back to you and thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

The problems of yours is linear.

Thus, what you can possibly do is to write the problem in matrix form and then look for the matrix kernel - which matlab computationally does (at least in terms of finding its directions, see e.g. http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/45457 ).

Here, though, we are assuming that the frequencies are real (provided it makes physical sense). Otherwise the problem is way harder.

Comment: In my case the frequencies are positive integers.